# Using Insertion-sort for sorting only odd numbers

Tags: java, numbers, insertion-sort

I want to sort the odd numbers using insertion sort in a given array and not touch the even numbers but the even numbers' position will be changing I don't want them to stay between odd numbers

EX:

```
int arr[] = {1,4,5,2,7,6,3,9,0}
The output should be = {1,3,5,7,9,4,2,6,0}
```

This is my code where I wrote the insertion code but I couldn't figure out the sorting of only the odd part of the problem

How can I sort odd numbers on the left side in ascending order while putting all the even numbers on the right side without sorting?

```
public void InsertionOdd(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        
        int key = a[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        
        while(j >= 0 && a[j] > key) {
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        
        a[j + 1] = key;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change two things:

1. add a validation after assigning the value to the key variable `int key = a[i]; if( key % 2 == 1)`
2. make sure to move the element selected to the left if the key is bigger than the a[j] or if the a[j] is a even number : `while (j >= 0 && (a[j] > key || a[j]% 2 == 0))`
   And now the code should work.

Comment: Try this  `int[] a = {-7, -10, -1, -2, -6, -5, 1, 1, 1, 9};`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method that takes a comparator.

When comparing two values `a` & `b` using `compare(a,b)` the comparator returns `-1, 0, 1` for `a < b, a == b, and a > b` respectively.  To build one for this method the comparator needs to treat even numbers specially so that they are pushed to the end of the list.  Since the desired order is ascending, `compare(a,b)` must return `-1`  when `a < b`.  To force that for even values of `a`, use `a % 2 == 0` which must return a `1`.  For `b`, `b % 2 == 0` which must return a `-1`.  Any other values of `a and b` will depend on the result of `a.compareTo(b)`.  This can be achieved using the ternary (`?:`) operator in the comparator.

```
Comparator<Integer> comp = (a,b)-> a % 2 == 0 ? 1 : b % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 
                                        a.compareTo(b);
```

So if a is even, it returns a `1`, if b is even it returns a `-1`, otherwise returns the result of the explicit compare.

Here is how it works in your method.

```
public static void InsertionOdd(int[] arr, Comparator<Integer> comp) {
    
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        
        while (j >= 0 && comp.compare(key, arr[j]) < 0){
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

Doing it like this has several advantages.

- You're not modifying any other part of your method other than the compare part.  So you can pass other comparators as well to sort in different manners.
- This also works on a mix of positive and negative numbers.

Note that you can code the comparator directly into the method.  However, it will not be as versatile if other sorts are desired.

Comment: If my answer is flawed please let me know.  And show the data that failed.

Comment: I just tried my solution and it worked.  It prints `[-7, -5, -1, 1, 1, 1, 9, -10, -2, -6]`

Comment: OK.  I'm confused.  You accepted my answer in spite of saying it had a flaw.  When I asked for an example I demonstrated that it worked.  Then you unaccepted my answer.  Could you please tell me what the problem is?